How to get the photo from camera, transfer it to antother activity and use it there in Android Studio
I have two java classes in my project in Android Studio. The MainActivity class and and the CropTrapezActivity class. The CropTrapezActivity class should take input from the camera, and cut it in a trapezoid form.
The code in the MainActivity class is:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 100;
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    Button launch_camera;

    Button change_activity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        change_activity = findViewById(R.id.change_activity);

        change_activity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectionActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        launch_camera = findViewById(R.id.launch_camera);
        launch_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CropTrapezActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("image", thumbnail);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}


The code in the CropTrapezActivity class is:
public class CropTrapezActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop_trapez);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);

        String mode = getIntent().getStringExtra("mode");

        switch (mode) {

            case "trapez":
                demoTrapez();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void demoTrapez() {

        btn.setText("Crop Trapez");

        findViewById(R.id.iv_display_trapez).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final ExtTrapezImageView extTrapezImageView = findViewById(R.id.iv_display_trapez);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inDensity = 0;
        options.inTargetDensity = 0;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample_1);

        extTrapezImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_capture).setOnClickListener(v -> extTrapezImageView.crop(new Result<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Void data) {
                extTrapezImageView.getCroppedBitmap(new Result<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bitmap data) {
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {

                            findViewById(R.id.iv_display_trapez).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            findViewById(R.id.iv_display_cropped).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            ((AppCompatImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_display_cropped))
                                    .setImageBitmap(data);
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(CropTrapezActivity.this,
                                "Could not get cropped bitmap" + throwable.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

            }
        }));
    }

}


I don't know how to change this line of code in CropTrapezActivity
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample_1);

in order to take input from the camera, not from drawable folder, and and crop it here.
Thank you
I tried the answers from this post, but nothing. How to launch camera and send photo taken to another activity
